# Azure Data Factory - Calling an activity based on OR logic output of prior activities

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In ADF, I created a pipeline for error handling. In my flow, I want to call this pipeline if any of the activities fails. In SSIS there is an option to use OR logic to achieve that, but in ADF, all outputs are uses AND logic, How can I Achieve OR logic so I can call the error pipeline if any of the prior activities fails?
The flow in screenshot I added won't work, because all activities should fail in order the email to send
[image: This flow works only if all activities fails]

Answer (score 0):

In **Azure Data Factory**, you cannot define any logic to connect activity to other activities, you can only add other activities upon

- Success
- Failure
- Completion
- Skipped

Here you need to add your execute pipeline activity to send error details to all the individual activities upon failure of each activity as required.

**Example:**

[image]

> When activity fails the next activity which is connected upon success will not be executed and the pipeline stops running if no activity is added upon failure individually.